# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-gadget

i am trying to create a google gadget which should be built on javascript.every google gadget create a iframe element.due to some constraints i can't add jquery directly from script tag.i have to include it using javascript so i write a code

```
function addScript(jsRelativeUrl) {
  var rebasedUrl = rebaseRelativeUrl(jsRelativeUrl,true);

 var x = document.createElement('script');
 x.type='"text/javascript"';
 x.src='"'+rebasedUrl+'"';
if(x.src.indexOf('scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')>=0)
 document.head.appendChild(x)
else document.body.appendChild(x);

}
```

i am first calling this function

```
gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(function(){
  addScript('scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
     $(function (){});
});
```

but it is giving me error

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

and when i see in elements jQuery is included in head tag of iframe .
can any one please help why i am getting this error and how to getrid of this ??

Comment: Make sure that you don't load any pluging before loadig jQuery

Comment: yes i am sure i am not loading any plugin and it is giving me error on the line i specified.

Comment: try `jQuery(function($){});` instead of `$(function (){});`

Comment: tried jQuery(function(){}) its giving me error jQuery is not defined

Comment: Looks like you need to add a callback to addScript, and place the jQuery inside that.

Answer (score -1):

You are appending the `script` tag to load jquery at the end of either the `head` or the `body`of the embedding document. if the code you are executing is situated before the location of the jquery import tag (eg. in a `script` section of the `head` or - if appended to the end of the `body`- in a `script`section within the `body`), it cannot be present.

Comment: i added jQUery in head and using it in body!!

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta: you should write so in your question (instead of downvoting, if that's been you). btw are you sure that you don't import jquery at the end of the body? have you checked the value of `x.src.indexOf('scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')` ?

Comment: yes i checked but it is not executing script only adding the child in head. i saw script tag of jquery in my dom

Comment: and apology if u mind downvoting next time i will keep this in mind

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta: have you tried to eval the dom nodes textual contents in order to track down the problem ? does the error also occur with the non-minified flavor of the script or with another version ? btw, i don't mind downvoting in general, in this particular case i just felt there was no reason.

Comment: i resolved the issue  x.src='"'+rebasedUrl+'"'; in this line link is going in this way ""http://www.fnsfsjflsjfldss.com/fkshfdskh"" and due to second " the error was now every thing is working perfectly fine

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta: congrats!